# Metamath - simple equation solution / proof

Tags: learning, metamath

Sorry if an improper question, looking into metamath and metamath-lamp and though it should be trivial to prove A = 2 -> ( A + 2 ) = 4, or the inverse.

But cant seem to get it right in metamath-lamp.

Starting with hypothesis
H ( A + 2 ) = 4

it should (?) be possible, even simple, to get to:

G A = 2

Started with:

```
- H        |- ( A + 2 ) = 4
- P 2p2e4  |- ( 2 + 2 ) = 4 
- P eqtr4i |- ( A + 2 ) = ( 2 + 2 )
```

After this, I'm blocked, cant find the steps that get to the goal: A = 2

Wouldn't some existing simplification do the trick? Does it exists in set.mm? How do I apply it?

Comment: I don’t know much about metamath, but the rule you propose is clearly false.  For example A * 0 = 0 * 0 does not imply A = 0.

Comment: Yes, true, thanks for ponting that. Don't know much about metamath also, but at some point when browsing metamath MPE I believe I saw some simplification theorems, that might do the trick, not that one for sure.  Edited my question.

Comment: [addcan2](https://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/addcan2.html)? Or [addcan2i](https://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/addcan2i.html) which will be easier to use.

Comment: Both look a good fit, will give it a try, thanks.

Comment: In your question you say you are trying to prove `A = 2 -> ( A + 2 ) = 4` but your proof looks like you are actually proving the converse (which is admittedly more interesting).

Comment: @JasonRute, you're right :) It's probably a dumb exercise, but trying to think how I can implement with metamath, but failing miserably, a simple equation solver. And ofc the result would be something like X = 2, or whatever, from some input equation. The "solver" would need to have a set of theorems to use, when searching for the solution, for basic equation manipulation and simplification. Guess this is something above my level.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no solver (yet?), one has to specify each step. Something like this works:
`h1::jagra.1          |- A e. CC`

`h2::jagra.2          |- ( 2 + A ) = 4`

`d2::2cn              |- 2 e. CC`

`10:d2,1,2:mvlladdi   |- A = ( 4 - 2 )`

`20::2p2e4            |- ( 2 + 2 ) = 4`

`40:d2,d2,20:mvlladdi |- 2 = ( 4 - 2 )`

`50:10,40:eqtr4i      |- A = 2`

Comment: That's it, thank you so much. Will you put this as an answer so I can accept it!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proof for the first direction: A = 2 -> ( A + 2 ) = 4

```
h1::jagra1.1         |- A = 2
2:1:oveq1i          |- ( A + 2 ) = ( 2 + 2 )
3::2p2e4            |- ( 2 + 2 ) = 4
qed:2,3:eqtri      |- ( A + 2 ) = 4
```

For the reverse direction, more proof steps are necessary. Especially, since
`A` is an unknown, you'll need to specify you're looking for a complex number:

```
h1::jagra.1          |- A e. CC
h2::jagra.2          |- ( A + 2 ) = 4
3::2p2e4             |- ( 2 + 2 ) = 4
4::2cn               |- 2 e. CC
5:1,4,2:mvlraddi    |- A = ( 4 - 2 )
6:4,4,3:mvlraddi    |- 2 = ( 4 - 2 )
qed:5,6:eqtr4i     |- A = 2
```

It is also possible to prove both directions directly as an equivalence:

```
h1::jagra.1         |- A e. CC
2::2cn               |- 2 e. CC
3::2p2e4             |- ( 2 + 2 ) = 4
4:1,2,2:addcan2i    |- ( ( A + 2 ) = ( 2 + 2 ) <-> A = 2 )
5:3:eqeq2i          |- ( ( A + 2 ) = ( 2 + 2 ) <-> ( A + 2 ) = 4 )
qed:5,4:bitr3i     |- ( ( A + 2 ) = 4 <-> A = 2 )
```